# Magento2: Move an element inside an existing element with XML Layout

Tags: xml, magento2

I am trying to move the layered navigation to somewhere specific on the page.

Here is the layout XML at `Magento_LayeredNavigation/page_layout/1column.xml`:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content" after="-"/>
</layout>
```

And this works fine, it moves the layered navigation into the content area. However I want to move the layered navigation into here (`category.products`):

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
```

Changing the layout XML at `Magento_LayeredNavigation/page_layout/1column.xml` to this doesn't work:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.products" after="-"/>
</layout>
```

Can anyone tell me the correct way to move an element inside an existing element?

Comment: you want to change for a specific page or want to change on all page?

Comment: either - once i can figure out how to move an element inside an existing element i should be able to figure out the rest

Answer (score 0):

Override `catalog_category_view.xml` to your Theme
Example app->design->frontend->pakage->theme->Magento_Catalog->layout->catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.product.list.additional" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Its for category page you can also override all pages